# apache virtual host redirect traffic works in LAN but not WAN

Tags: apache, ubuntu, redirect, virtualhost, owncloud

I have a domain hosted by yahoo.

But i am using my own in house server to actually host my Domain and cloud sub domain.

so in the Yahoo, i forward all www.mydomain.com to my static ip

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://111.111.111.111">
```

and all my sub-domain traffic to my static ip:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://111.111.111.111/cloud"  />
```

My in-house server is Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  I have created a virtual host site and enabled it and it works very well as long as i am in the LAN.  When i am on the WAN, however, the web browser times out saying that the server stopped working.
I think i know where the problem is, but i am not sure how to solve it, namely in the redirect to the htpps - i am using a LAN IP.  Using my static IP or my domain name did not help me solve this.  here is my enabled site for my virtual host:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin admin@myexample.com
       ServerName www.myexample.com
       ServerAlias myexample.com

       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example-test/

       Alias /   /var/www/html/example-test/

       ### Redirect /cloud   https://www.myexample.com/cloud
       Redirect /cloud   https://192.168.1.122/cloud
       ### Redirect /cloud   https://111.111.111.111/cloud

       <Directory /var/www/html/example-test>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
       </Directory>

       <Directory /var/www/owncloud>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
       </Directory>

       ErrorLog /var/log/apache_http_myexample.com.error.log
    </VirtualHost>


    ### <VirtualHost www.myexample.com:443>
    <VirtualHost 192.168.1.122:443>
    ### <VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:443>
       ServerAdmin admin@myexample.com
       ServerName www.myexample.com
       ServerAlias myexample.com

       Alias /cloud   /var/www/owncloud
       DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud/
       ####Configuration for SSL #####
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/examplecloud.pem
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/examplecloud.key
       #### End of SSL Configuration ####


       <Directory /var/www/owncloud>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
       </Directory>

       ErrorLog /var/log/apache_https_cloud.myexample.com.error.log
    </VirtualHost>
```

~

Any help/insight would be much appreciated...

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try `Redirect permanent /cloud   https://192.168.1.122/cloud`

If that didn't work, try a more generic solution by replacing Redirect with:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: one thing i noticed, i can access owncloud from our guest network ... i did not expect that.  i was thinking it is a DNS issue, but now i am thinking it is a firewall issue